# C# XNA - Calculating next point in a vector direction

Tags: c#, vector, xna

lets say i have two points **A** & **B** in my 3D Space

[image]

now i want to start calculate points from **A** to **B** in direction of **B** and i want to continue calculation farther from B on the same line.

**How t do it ?**

what i am actually working on is bullets from plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you should first get the direction vector by calculating

```
dir = B - A
```

and then you can continue the travel by

```
C = B + dir
```

Otherwise, please clarify your question, like for example what you mean by "calculate points from A to B", because mathematically there is an infinite amount of points between A and B.

---

Edit:
If you want to trace a bullet path you have two options:

1) You implement it as *hitscan* weapon like done in many FPS; any bullets fired will immediately hit where they were aimed. This can be best achieved by doing a raytrace via [Ray.Intersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.ray.intersects.aspx) and is probably the simplest and least computationally intensive way to do it. Of course, it's also not terribly realistic.

2) You make the bullet a physical entity in your world and move it during your `Update()` call via a "normal" combination of current position vector and movement/velocity vector, doing a manual collision detection with any hittable surfaces and objects. The advantage of this is that you can implement proper physics like travel time, drop, friction, etc., however it is also orders of magnitude more difficult to implement in a robust way. If you want to go this way, I suggest using either a pre-made physics API (like [Bullet](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/), but I'm not sure if there's a version for XNA) or at least doing extensive Google research on the subject, so you can avoid the many pitfalls of collision detection with fast-moving objects.

Comment: this technique is working for 2D planes.. i am in 3D.. see my self answer to this question to see what is happening or what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

its a try to implement a 2D technique in 3D, i calculate the following once

```
position = start;
dx = destination.X - start.X;
dy = destination.Y - start.Y;
dz = destination.Z - start.Z;

distance = (float)Math.Sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz );
scale = 2f / distance;
```

then i go on calculating

```
position.X += dx * scale;
position.Y += dy * scale;
position.Z += dz * scale;
```

but the result is still is not working of 3D Space, i am getting result for only 2 Dimension, the third axis is not being changed

Comment: Surely you meant `position.Z += dz * scale;`? Though why you do all the calculation manually even though XNA has lots of helper functions and overloaded operators with the Vector3 class is a mystery to me.

Comment: i don't know them man. i am new to matrices and vectors and 3D

Comment: `Vector3 dir = destination - start; var scale = 2f / dir.Length(); dir *= scale; position += dir;`